# How to access Google contacts from C++ service?

Tags: c++, google-people-api

I have a service written in C++ that manages pbap contacts. Now I want to integrate google contacts into my service. I have observed that Google Contacts C++ API is deprecated and in People API there is no client library for C++ language. Is there a way/(s) to integrate google contacts into C++ service?

Comment: It's just a REST API that you access via whatever REST client library you prefer. https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest

Comment: As the Contacts API is a REST API, you can access it in C++ using a library like curl

Comment: I see some deprecated google client libraries for C++. Is there any active google provided client libraries for OAuth 2.0 user authorization?